# Plug Postgres database on Navicat using prisma

Tags: docker, docker-compose, navicat, prisma

Im currently doing an app using Prisma and a Postgres database and I can't connect my database to Navicat. I'm a beginner with docker and dont understand completely how services work. My current `docker-compose.yml` is

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.8
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        databases:
          default:
            connector: postgres
            host: postgres
            port: 5432
            user: prisma
            password: prisma
            migrations: true
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: prisma
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: prisma
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  postgres:
```

And what I tried on Navicat is [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcB5p.png), what seems to me correct but it would appear that no.

Thank you for you help !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use [port mapping](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#ports) using the `ports` property for your `postgres` container:

```
version: '3'
services:
  prisma:
    image: prismagraphql/prisma:1.8
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "4466:4466"
    environment:
      PRISMA_CONFIG: |
        port: 4466
        # uncomment the next line and provide the env var PRISMA_MANAGEMENT_API_SECRET=my-secret to activate cluster security
        # managementApiSecret: my-secret
        databases:
          default:
            connector: postgres
            host: postgres
            port: 5432
            user: prisma
            password: prisma
            migrations: true
  postgres:
    image: postgres
    restart: always
    ports:
    - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_USER: prisma
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: prisma
    volumes:
      - postgres:/var/lib/postgresql/data
volumes:
  postgres:
```

Then you should be able to connect to `localhost:5432` with a Postgres client, like Navicat.